# MacOS unified log with oslog crate

Tags: macos, rust, rust-cargo, oslog

I'd like to write to Apple's unified log on macOS from Rust.

I found the oslog crate which seems promising and I have the following code so far:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
use oslog::OsLogger;

fn main() {
    //env_logger::init();

    OsLogger::new("com.rust")
        //.level_filter(LevelFilter::Trace)
        .init()
        .unwrap();

    info!("starting up");
}
```

If I use the commented `env_logger` I can see the logs show up in Terminal, but with OSLogger - nothing shows up in the Console.app on macOS or if I stream the log like so:

```
log stream --predicate 'subsystem == "com.rust"'
```

Anyone here have done this? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, no experience with Rust yet.

Comment: Oh... it seems OSLogger requires a filter level set, otherwise it filters all logs out — i.e. writes no logs. Now it's working

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there were 2 parts to solving this and I'm posting the full code below.

First of all, you have to set an environment variable that enables logging when running the program. The value sets the level of log filtering to apply:

```
$ RUST_LOG=trace ./myrustprogram
```

Secondly, you have to set matching log levels when creating the oslog facade via `level_filter(...)`:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
use oslog::OsLogger;
use log::LevelFilter;

fn main() {
    OsLogger::new("com.rust")
        .level_filter(LevelFilter::Info)
        .init()
        .unwrap();

    info!("Hello from Rust: true");
    info!("Velocity: 2");
}
```

This writes to the unified log and can be observed via Console.app on macOS